# Mysqli dynamic query bind_results

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, database-performance, sqlperformance

I wrote one databasse class which I use often and I used mysqli.I wanted to write it with PDO but it was slow (It is not about ip connection :) ),and my website is really huge and this pdo little slowness will be really big problem,that's why I choosed difficult way --Mysqli--.I wrote some dynamic class which bind params dynamicly and easily  usage like this:

```
DB::getInstance()->query(sql,'ss',array($a,$b));
```

This was really useful untill today.I wanted to get result and also count values but I discover reaally big problem that when I use num_rows mysqli get_result will not work,When I use get_result num rows will never work,also when I use get_result and if I want to use it again for same query second one will not work
.Also get_result is not good function because it support only mysqlid.Then I have tried bind result which is useless because every select query I should write bind_result(params) which is not good for other developers on company also.What Should I do?Pdo is slow and for my website it is really slow,mysqli is not for developers it increase development time.How can I bind results dinamicly for query?I want something like I will write sql statement and bind result should get column names dinamicly bind them aoutomaticly and then I will write fetch() and I will write column names and I will get result.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use get_result num rows will never work

this is not true
besides, you never need num rows anyway

> when I use get_result and if I want to use it again for same query

you don't want it

> get_result is not good function because it support only mysqlid

this is true
however, if your site is so big and distinct, there is no problem to install a required module or two.

> How can I bind results dinamicly for query?

use get_result.

To reuse a result get all the rows into array using fetch_all() and then use this array anywhere you wish

Instead of num_rows just fetch the data and see whether anything was fetched or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer.Ok i used get_result again and it worked fine but problem is that there are two class and in first one I should get are there result or not (Ok I can do it with fetch) and then if there are it should return
fetch all to second one.How can I achive that with using only one fetch method?Also when I want to return fetch array ,then I try to  while($a = $b) it doesnt work and became endless loop.($b is variable which is contain returned fetch_all())

Comment: well, single result is a subset of a multiple result. you can always fetch all rows and then just take the first one if you need only one. but I strongly suggest to have dedicated functions to get different kinds of results. just looks at pdo, there are fetchColumn(), fetch() and fetchAll()

Comment: As you mention,why I dont need num_rows?Isnot it fast than fetch_all?
Also there are problem with checkiing result with fetch_all because 
when I write if($get_res->fetch_all) it always return false;.But also when I use num_rows with get_result it doesnt work.How can I check :are there result with fast way?

Comment: I tried also use two time fetch all first one in first class which detect are there result and second one in second class which fetch all data in while loop but again same kind of problem second fetch_all is not work(like second get_result or num_rows).How can I check are there result in one class and fetch them in another class?

Comment: Do you understand that fetch_all returns a variable that you can use as many times as you wish?

Comment: Yes of course.But when I do it with one fetch_all  I should return fetch to using again in another class and this is problem because when I do it , I should write something like : while($a = $b) it doesnt work and became endless loop.($b is variable which is contain returned fetch_all() I mentioned it before also );For now I just return query and then I do while($a = $b->fetch_all) ($b is query).But If I use fetch all before to check result exists it will not run

Comment: how can I use returned fetch_all with while ?It doesnt work like while($a=$b) this became endless loop.Are there way to do this?

Comment: to iterate over an array you have to use foreach, not while

Comment: Ok.Finally I solved this issue with deleted all my codes which about this issue and rewrite with totally different approach.Thank you so much for your advices they also helped me :).But I want to ask that as you mention dont use mysqli num rows Is mysqli num rows slow?Should I use fetch or mysqli num rows when I need only check if result exist?

Comment: you just never need it. by using num rows you are always doing double job.

Comment: Wow I also solve this problem with foreach I tried foreach loop again but with fetch_all(mysqli_assoc);
Thank you,you helped me a lot.I have tried solve this problem with a lot of ways and approaches(with a very long way) because I want to get best result for developers and servers(performance). and now I worked again with foreach and some rewrites and this workes just perfect.:)

Comment: @Alex I am glad you solved all problems. I'd like to take a look at your code, if you don't mind. I am interested in database wrappers in general.

Comment: I wanted to give but you know it is DB function and contain some specific informations that I have no right to make it public.You are great man thank you again :)